# Linking the static version of a library instead of the dynamic one

Tags: gcc, libjpeg

I am trying to use [libjpeg](http://www.ijg.org/) in my application. Making the project yields a libjpeg.a in .libs folder. What I would like to do is to use this file in the linkage stage. I have tried the following: I copied the libjpeg.a into the folder where my C code resides. Trying to link with

```
gcc libjpeg.a mycode.c -o executable_name
```

fails. If I do gcc -ljpeg mycode.c, the compilation is successful when I change my header to point to  instead of "libjpeg.h", but this obviously links to the system-wide dynamic version of the library.

Trying to link with relative or absolute path also fails:

```
gcc ./libjpeg.a mycode.c -o executable_name
```

I have tried the static option as well:

```
gcc -static libjpeg.a mycode.c -o executable_name
```

The linker error is the following:

```
Linking...
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -g -pedantic ./libjpeg.a ./libjpeg.a -lm obj/read_jpeg.o obj/utils.o -o test_jpeg
obj/read_jpeg.o: In function `read_JPEG_file':
/home/ustun/Downloads/jpeg_test/read_jpeg.c:37: undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error'
/home/ustun/Downloads/jpeg_test/read_jpeg.c:45: undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateDecompress'
/home/ustun/Downloads/jpeg_test/read_jpeg.c:46: undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_src'
/home/ustun/Downloads/jpeg_test/read_jpeg.c:47: undefined reference to `jpeg_read_header'
/home/ustun/Downloads/jpeg_test/read_jpeg.c:48: undefined reference to `jpeg_start_decompress'
/home/ustun/Downloads/jpeg_test/read_jpeg.c:62: undefined reference to `jpeg_read_scanlines'
/home/ustun/Downloads/jpeg_test/read_jpeg.c:74: undefined reference to `jpeg_finish_decompress'
/home/ustun/Downloads/jpeg_test/read_jpeg.c:75: undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy_decompress'
obj/read_jpeg.o: In function `read_JPEG_file_props':
/home/ustun/Downloads/jpeg_test/read_jpeg.c:93: undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error'
/home/ustun/Downloads/jpeg_test/read_jpeg.c:100: undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateDecompress'
/home/ustun/Downloads/jpeg_test/read_jpeg.c:101: undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_src'
/home/ustun/Downloads/jpeg_test/read_jpeg.c:102: undefined reference to `jpeg_read_header'
/home/ustun/Downloads/jpeg_test/read_jpeg.c:103: undefined reference to `jpeg_start_decompress'
/home/ustun/Downloads/jpeg_test/read_jpeg.c:113: undefined reference to `jpeg_read_scanlines'
/home/ustun/Downloads/jpeg_test/read_jpeg.c:116: undefined reference to `jpeg_finish_decompress'
/home/ustun/Downloads/jpeg_test/read_jpeg.c:117: undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy_decompress'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test_jpeg] Error 1
```

You can download a simple project with a Makefile [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/83342/jpeg_test.tar.gz).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd have to give the full path to `libjpeg.a`, If you have libjpeg.a in a .libs folder relative to where you compile:

```
gcc  mycode.c -o executable_name .libs/libjpeg.a
```

If your special libjpeg.a is elsewhere, give a full path to it.

If this fails, you have to tell us what happens. (the details are important, so please copy paste the exact errors and the exact command line that is run).

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the right track, but I still am getting linkage errors. Libjpeg also creates a .la file, maybe I need to link against that too?

Comment: I think this did it actually! The library needs to come at the end. I will take another look and accept this probably.

Comment: I'd concur to nos' answer. Remember for the future that linker arguments are very sensitive to the order of their call (in general: Objects can only find functions they link to towards the right of a linker line, never to the left). When .la objects are in the game, these are libtool objects, and you can either use libtool to link to them or find the real objects in .libs.

Comment: "Objects can only find functions they link to towards the right of a linker line, never to the left)" Oh, that's surprising! I thought it would be just the reverse, first give the library, then the file that uses it. I also remember reading that order didn't matter in modern compilers, but it seems to matter in this case.

Comment: It matters for static(.a) libraries. They have to be specified in the reverse order of dependencies on the command line. With shared(.so) libraries , the order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use -static:

```
gcc -static -o exec_name mycode.c -ljpeg
```

No need to copy the archive (.a). You could have found out by reading man ld.

Comment: I am trying to link to my specific version of libjpeg.a, not the system-wide one.

Comment: Then you'll have to give us the linker error with which your approach fails.

Comment: Thanks, I have included the linker error, but it doesn't seem to say much. I have included a sample project if you'd like to take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you if you have the same problem as mine.  In my system, I have

libjpeg.so.62 -> libjpeg.so.62.0.0
libjpeg.so.62.0.0

After I added symbolic link:

sudo ln -s libjpeg.so.62 libjpeg.so

My problem got solved.